# How to use specific packages in xamarin

Tags: mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

currently I'm developing a small app for myself using xamarin. Now I want to use https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart for my project but there isn't a package which I can use for both os.

In the readme they've added a xamarin port but I don't know how to use it. So could you please explain to me whether I can use this for my project or do I've to search for an another opportunity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "Both OS"? This is an Android only package.

> MPAndroidChart ⚡️ is a powerful & easy to use chart library for Android. It runs on API level 8 and upwards.

For the Xamarin.Android Port(A binding project of the Java project):

https://github.com/Flash3001/MPAndroidChart.Xamarin

> The major release for version 3.0.0 is now available, you can download it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.0

So you can easily download this from NuGet into your Xamarin.Android project.

There is note of an Xamarin.iOS Port(Not necessarily the same library here, but giving you the cross platform functionality):

https://github.com/Flash3001/iOSCharts.Xamarin

Which can also be found on NuGet:

> If you updated to Xcode 8 there's a version of this library uploaded in NuGet pre-release channel. https://www.nuget.org/packages/iOSCharts/2.2.5.2-xcode8

Comment: Thank you for your response! "Both OS" means that I'm using xamarin.forms for my project. I already seen that there is an Android package and an iOS package. My question is now do I've to use both packages, more specifically can I use them for my project? And if it's possible, how can I use each of the package for each specific os?

Comment: You can reference each platform package in it's own project and then use a `DependencyService`: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/